# How can I calculate the sum of two `pandas.DataFrame` based on `pandas.DataFrame.index`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

### What I want to achieve

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
index1 = ['I1', 'I2']
index2 = ['I1', 'I3']
columns = ['C1', 'C2']

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index1, columns=columns)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index2, columns=columns)

print(df1)
#    C1  C2
#I1   1   2
#I2   3   4

print(df2)
#    C1  C2
#I1   1   2
#I3   3   4

print(...) # Calculate somehow
## !!!!!Expected Result!!!!!
#    C1  C2
#I1   2   4
#I2   3   4
#I3   3   4
```

The expected result is a dataframe whose values are like below.

- I1: the sum of two dataframes because both `df1` and `df2` have a row named `'I1'`.
- I2: use the value of `df1.loc['I2']` because `df2` doesn't have this index.
- I3: use the value of `df2.loc['I3']` because `df1` doesn't have this index.

### What I tested

```
print(df1.add(df2, axis='index'))
#    C1  C2
#I1 2.0 4.0
#I2 NaN NaN
#I3 NaN NaN

print(pd.concat([df1, df2]))
#    C1  C2
#I1   1   2
#I2   3   4
#I1   1   2
#I3   3   4

print(df1 + df2.values)
#    C1  C2
#I1   2   4
#I2   6   8
```

Could you help me get the expect result?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the addition" in the title? In other words, what if your dfs would have elements with the same index? would you want to perform a sum? or are you just interested on stacking the two dfs?

Comment: @pedrosaurio Hi I updated the word to "sum"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `DataFrame.add()`

```
df = df1.add(df2, fill_value=0)
```

dataframe matches your output but may need to fix dtypes
you can use

```
df["C1"] = df["C1"].astype(np.int64)
 
df["C2"] = df["C2"].astype(np.int64)
```

for not using with numpy, use just `int` instead of `np.int64` in the code

for documentation on this see [Pandas Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html)

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is the df.combine method
This method combines both of your dataframes together with a given, function just like the docs show

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine.html

So basically what you need to do is the following,

```
func = lambda s1,s2: s1+s2
df3 = df1.combine(df2,func,fill_value=0)
print(df3)
```

This gives you a little more flexibility than add

Answer (score 2):

Try chain with `groupby`

```
out = pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby(level=0).sum()
Out[161]: 
    C1  C2
I1   2   4
I2   3   4
I3   3   4
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it using combine_first, successively

```
df3=df3.combine_first(df1).combine_first(df2)
df3
```

```
     C1      C2
I1  2.0     4.0
I2  3.0     4.0
I3  3.0     4.0
```